# Convex polygon algorithm in Cuda?

Tags: c, performance, cuda, convex-polygon

I am searching for an algorithm to find a convex polygon to contain all the random points using Cuda. Is there anyone know a very efficient algorithm that I can adapt?

Comment: Is this not just the standard Convex Hull problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull ?

Comment: it's a convex hull in 3d, it's actually standard. But the problem is to find an efficient algorithm to map to CUDA GPU multi-thread.

Answer (score 3):

If you (or future SO users) are still looking for a 3D Hull algorithm for CUDA, you might check out this paper from November 2011:

"CudaHull: Fast Parallel 3D Convex Hull on the GPU"
by Ayal Stein, Eran Geva, and Jihad El-Sana

http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~el-sana/publications/pdf/CudaHull.pdf

The authors claim a 27x to 40x speedup over Qhull (http://www.qhull.org) for 10 and 20 million points, respectively. For fewer points (< 10,000), though, their CPU / GPU algorithm is actually slower than Qhull.

I haven't implemented it myself, but came across both your SO question and the CudaHull paper when searching for 3D convex hull algorithms for CUDA.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [paper presented at HiPC](http://www.hipc.org/hipc2009/documents/HIPCSS09Papers/1569255641.pdf) about running a [Convex Hull Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) on a GPU with CUDA.

[Graham Scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) is a simple algorithm to find the Convex Hull of a set of points. On the Wikipedia article exists a pseudo code version of it.

Comment: yeah, I know that paper, however, it's a two-D version. Plus, Graham Scan seems to be impossible to extend to 3d. But thanks anyway for the answer